# Rails 5 rename CRUD route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following Rails 5 resources, and I want the URL to show `/welcome` on `huddles#index` (as well as for the `huddles_path` url helper). e.g, I don't want `huddles_welcome_path`. Can this be done? Thank you!

```
  resources :huddles do
    get '/welcome', to: 'huddles#index'
    resources :invitations
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  resources :huddles do
   get '/welcome', to: 'huddles#index', :as => :huddles_path
   resources :invitations
  end
```

Just Add a :as => :namethatyouwant

Answer (score 2):

Move the route outside of the `huddles` resource if you don't want to include `huddles/` in the route:

```
resources :huddles do
  resources :invitations
end

get '/welcome', to: 'huddles#index'
```

Comment: I would like to go to `/welcome` using `huddles_path`. This doesn't seem to do that.